# representing a binom in a $\sum$ sort of way

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

i need to represent a binom in a $\sum$ sort of way.

how can i represent disturbing k identical balls into 10 different baskets, but which consits of two groups: 7 and 3(all of them are seperate, i just need to calculate the 10 different baskets in 2 groups: 7 and 3).

so the binom i got is: $D(7,k)+D(3,k)=\binom {7+k-1}{k} + \binom {3+k-1}{k}$

how can i turn it into a $\sum$ sort of representation?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want a sum instead of the normal product/factorial expression? Also, is it at all important what the terms are that you are summing?

Comment: that what i was asked to do. 
they asked that the k balls would be placed into 10 different baskets, where 7 had one color and the 3 had different. it was very hard to understand what they wanted

Answer (score 1):

Well, by stars and bars you can do $\binom{k+9}{9}$ distributions, but if you have $7$ marked, you can decide how many balls goes in this $7$ marked baskets as $$\sum _{i = 0}^k\underbrace{\binom{i+6}{6}}_{\text{distribute $i$ balls in 7.}}\underbrace{\binom{k-i+2}{2}}_{\text{  distribute $n-i$ in 3.}}.$$

So $$\binom{k+9}{9}=\sum _{i = 0}^k \binom{i+6}{6}\binom{k-i+2}{2}.$$

Comment: thank you very much! really great and simple